# Getter value keeps returning null Java

Tags: java

I am trying to pass the objects by using getter and setter method. It works when I use System.out.println("test: "+this.admin); but I can't get the objects when I call System.out.println("WHY YOU ARE NOT WORKING?! "+getAdmin());

Here is the output of the program:

```
test: entity.account.Admin@18a607c2

WHY YOU ARE NOT WORKING?! null
```

Admin Master panel panel page

```
 public class AdminMasterPanel extends JPanel {

    protected JFrame myFrame;

    private Admin admin;


    public Admin getAdmin() {
        return admin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(Admin admin) {
       this.admin = admin;
       System.out.println("test: "+this.admin);
    }


    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    public AdminMasterPanel(JFrame mf) {

       // Set the frame to the program
       myFrame = mf;
       setLayout(null);
       setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 720);

       System.out.println("WHY YOU ARE NOT WORKING?! "+getAdmin());


     }
}
```

Calling setAdmin method from other class to set the admin objects:

```
AdminMasterPanel amp = new AdminMasterPanel(null); 
amp.setAdmin(admin);
```

Comment: You're saying the output from the constructor appears *after* the output from the setter?

Comment: The program make a getAdmin() in the constructor, so before the setAdmin() call

Comment: No what I mean is that I keep getting null when I call it from the constructor.

Comment: And what Hacketo is saying is that it's perfectly normal since the setter that initializes the admin is called **after** the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you call `getAdmin()` before `setAdmin()`.
Your constructor does not even get a `Admin` Object. So you are basically calling nothing with `getAdmin()`.

What you have todo is this:

```
public AdminMasterPanel(JFrame mf, Admin admin) {

   // Set the frame to the program
   myFrame = mf;
   setLayout(null);
   setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 720);
   this.admin = admin;
   System.out.println("WHY YOU ARE NOT WORKING?! "+getAdmin());
 }
```

Or since it seems like you want to set the admin with the object method `setAdmin()`. You have to remove the `Sysout` in your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

where is your class constructor to initialize all the variables?

If you want to leave out the constructor, at least do this:

```
private Admin admin = new Admin();
```

The reason you get `nullPointerException` is because you are trying to access a non-existing object.

---

**Crash course on Classes & Objects:**

```
Admin admin; //Doing this DOES NOT create an object
```

The above does not create any Admin object. What it does is create a reference which points to nothing (null).

You only create objects when you use the `new` keyword.

```
new Admin(); //Create an Admin Object

Admin admin = new Admin();  //Create an Admin object and reference it with a  variable named "admin".
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is the problem.

```
private Admin admin;
```

admin is not initialized anywhere, so its default value is null.
Since you have called `getAdmin()` inside the constructor, it is being executed before the `setAdmin(admin)` gets invoked.

So `getAdmin()` returns null.